# how to send keys to this item

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

the web codes:

```
<input id="black_box_name" size="30" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
    <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">108 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span> 
        <input type="hidden" id="black_box_id" name="black_box_id" value="124">
```

I try to send keys to this input item, but cannot. I use
 `xpath: "//input[@id = 'black_box_id']"` 
 The system complains `'Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated'`

Comment: <input id="black_box_name" size="30" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
<span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">108 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
<input type="hidden" id="black_box_id" name="black_box_id" value="124">

Comment: xpth is working for me, gives list of target tags.

Comment: this could be helpful :https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11637 . it says using protractor.js, setting window size can fixed this error...driver.manage().window().setSize(1000, 800);

Comment: You try to send keys to an element who is hidden. Try to send keys to black_box_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this and it works:

```
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='black_box_name']").send_keys(ticketTestData["inputSpecial"]["//*[@id='black_box_name']"])
            x_path = "//a[text() = " + "'" + ticketTestData["inputSpecial"]["//*[@id='black_box_name']"] + "'" + "]"
            logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " xpath " + x_path)
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, medium_timeout/6).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, x_path)))
            element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You sent to wrong element. element you indicated is hidden. you should use:

```
//input[@id = 'black_box_name']
```

by the way, already you have a unique id, so you can optimize by select id:

```
id = "black_box_name"
```

Comment: I used the way you mentioned, it will pop up the error: "Black Box Id not numeric"